# How to interrupt and continue downloading many wget files without repetitons?

Tags: wget, download

I am downloading ~330k scientific files with `wget` from a csv file containing the URLs of the files I need to download. So, I am using the command

```
wget -i all_the_urls.csv
```

and my file `all_the_urls.csv` looks something like this

```
http://dr16.sdss.org/sas/dr16/sdss/spectro/redux/v5_13_0/spectra/lite/11040/spec-11040-58456-0109.fits
http://dr16.sdss.org/sas/dr16/sdss/spectro/redux/v5_13_0/spectra/lite/11068/spec-11068-58488-0780.fits
http://dr16.sdss.org/sas/dr16/sdss/spectro/redux/v5_13_0/spectra/lite/11068/spec-11068-58488-0240.fits
```

The files are small, ~ 250 kB each. But their amount is so large that I will need to sometimes interrupt the download and then continue the download again. Is there a `wget` command to use so that I can continue the download where I left of, after the last downloaded file, not at the beginning of the list of URLs?

If there is no such command can you tell me how I can use one of the following work-arounds (I am not aware of `wget`):

- after `wget` downloads a file make it erase the URL of this file inside `all_the_urls.csv`
- before `wget` downloads a new file make it check if this file is already downloaded and if it is, skip to the next file (not sure how time expensive this checking will be though)

Any other ideas are also welcome! tnx

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`-c` for continue & possible `-nc` for no clobber should work.

You may be better to look at `mirror` although the docs on that are poor.

Comment: Thank you, it looks like `-nc` is what I am looking for, it starts right after the file where I left of! `-c` on the other hand does some long checks and takes ~1sec/file, so it is definitely not an option for my case with 300k files

Comment: There is a possibility then that a file may only be partially downloaded. If you can, I would see about some form of a crc listing of the directory contents.

Comment: @NeStack, just check what happens for the partial file if you interrupt the download mid-file. At least the `wget` I looked at happily leaves the partial file _with the correct filename_, and after that `-nc` ignores it. `-c` at least continues the download, since like you said, it checks the file size from the server, for each file.

Comment: An alternative would be to create a file listing, iterate through it, then delete on a successful transfer. Or add it to a _done_ list and check there.